# Google Assistant working but not showing up

Tags: google-assistant, android-11

Since a few days, my Google Assistant has a strange behavior: when I long press home button, it works fine and shows himself like in the image

[image: Screenshot of Google Assistant listening for command]

but this window doesn't show up when I say "Ok Google" or "Hey Google". The assistant does work and replies vocally to my commands, but I want it to also show up like in the image. It used to show up on voice interaction until some days ago

**Phone**: Samsung Galaxy A71 
**Android version**: 11 
**One UI version**: 3.1 
**Google version**: 12.24.10.23.arm64 (updated on 23 Jun)

Answer (score 0):

Just updated Google app and the problem solved